# BuildConfigField generation issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

To reproduce the issue just add this code to your `android` block in the `gradle.build` file

```
flavorDimensions "dimension"    
productFlavors {
    Works {
        dimension "dimension"
    }

    DoesNotWork {
        dimension "dimension"
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.buildConfigField("boolean", "test", "true")

        tasks.findAll {
            it.name.startsWith("foo")
        }.each {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the `test` variable is only going to be generated for the `Works` flavor. There seems to be a problem with the `tasks.findAll` call: If I remove it, there will be no issue with `DoesNotWork` flavor anymore. Android gradle plugin version is 4.1.2. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: "there will be no issue with DoesNotWork flavor anymore" -- but... what is the issue?

Comment: The test variable is not generated for this flavor...

Comment: FWIW, it works if you move your `tasks.findAll {}.each {}` out of that `applicationVariants.all {}` and just have it at the top level of `app/build.gradle`.

Comment: not an option for me due to implementation details in "do something". It would also not work, if I move it to another `applicationVariants.all` block...